# Rowdeleting on my string ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `gv_Storagepricing_RowDeleting` method

```
protected void gv_Storagepricing_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string result = null;
    storageprice ss = new storageprice();
    string categoryID = gv_Storagepricing.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    result = ss.StoragePricingDelete(categoryID);
}
```

this is the code of `StoragePricingDelete` method

```
public string StoragePricingDelete(string ID)
{
    string queryStr = "DELETE FROM StoragePricing WHERE Pricing_ID = @ID";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    conn.Open();
    int nofRow = 0;
    nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return nofRow;
}
```

The error states

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

I'm really new to this.

Comment: `result = ss.StoragePricingDelete();`?  Missing brackets?  You'd have to show us how `StoragePricingDelete` is defined inside the `storageprice` class.

Comment: The error states that "Cannot convert method group 'StoragePricingDelete' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?' may i know what it means, please help me thanks.

Comment: @Colin you should add that error statement in your question, not in comment :)

Comment: @sstan hi sstan I added the parameter in , and I get error states that cannot implicitly convert type 'id' to 'string'. Sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: What is `id`?  If it's an integer, then you can always do `id.ToString()` to convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are not invoking the `StoragePricingDelete` method as you are probably intending.

To invoke a method, you need to write the method call with `()` at the end, and perhaps some parameters between the brackets, as is your case.

Without the brackets, you are attempting to pass a reference to the method to the `int` variable (obviously invalid), instead of invoking the method and assigning the method's return value to your variable.

In this case, you'll need to call the method like this:

```
result = ss.StoragePricingDelete("pricing id value goes here");
```

... where you have to pass in your pricing id parameter between the brackets.  Not sure what the correct value for that is, you'll have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your code of `StoragePricingDelete` method below

```
public string StoragePricingDelete(string ID)
{
    string queryStr = "DELETE FROM StoragePricing WHERE Pricing_ID = @ID";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    conn.Open();
    int nofRow = 0;
    nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return nofRow;
}
```

When you have this

```
public string StoragePricingDelete(string ID)
```

You're telling the compiler that `StoragePricingDelete` returns a `string`, however what you're returning is `nofRow`

```
    int nofRow = 0;
    nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return nofRow;
```

which is clearly an `int`, so that's why you got the error. You can fix the error by returning `nofRow.ToString()` as below

```
public string StoragePricingDelete(string ID)
{
    string queryStr = "DELETE FROM StoragePricing WHERE Pricing_ID = @ID";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    conn.Open();
    int nofRow = 0;
    nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return nofRow.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you cannot run a debug yet because of this line of code :
`return nofRow;`
as it should be `return nofRow.ToString();`